# How to Insert SELECT ALL values or SELECTED checkboxes values into different columns in mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox, insert

I want to Insert **SELECT ALL** values or **SELECTED** values into different columns in MySQL. On choosing `SELECT ALL`, all the values are inserting correctly in sql but on selecting some checkboxes data is not inserting in SQL data.

Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#select_all").change(function(){
    var status = this.checked;
    $('.checkbox').each(function(){
        this.checked = status;
    });
});

$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked == false){
        $("#select_all")[0].checked = false;
}

if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length ){ 
        $("#select_all")[0].checked = true;
}
});
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$addbook=$_POST['addbook'];
$memdet=$_POST['memdet'];
$vbookd=$_POST['vbookd'];
$modify=$_POST['modify'];
$result=mysqli_query($db,"insert into apanel(addbook,memdet,vbookd,modify)values('$addbook','$memdet','$vbookd','$modify')");
?>
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Selecct All<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="addbook" />Add Book<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="memdet" />View Member Details<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="vbookd" />View Book Details<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="modify" />Edit/Delete<br>
```

***I want to insert selective checkboxes also in MYSQL database.*** Help required

Comment: I'm betting that your db doesn't allow for empty values. This is an answer in its own right. `mysqli_error($db)` will tell you what's going on, or not.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Please read the question. Mysql is inserting the values on click SELECT ALL. Issue is only when some checkboxes are selected. No problem with db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before inserting into mysql check if the value is exist in `$_POST['addbook']` do this for all the checkboxes. You can also use array of checkbox.

```
     <?php
       // Do this for rest of the values also.

            if (isset($_POST['addbook'])){

               $addbook=$_POST['addbook'];

            }else{

               $addbook = "default value"

            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This Works but lengthy process. Can it be a liitle short?

Comment: There is way to use array of checkbox.